# Session Invalidation while switching to HTTPS using AWS Load Balancer and tomcat 6 instance

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having some problem with SSL, Load Balancer and Tomcat.
I have a tomcat instance, running on 8080 port, which is accessible and working perfectly.
My application is on *SPRING* framework and it switches to HTTPS for some secure pages [like account/checkout etc.]
The secure port running on tomcat is 8443.
For a standalone tomcat server, everything is working as expected, switching between secure and non-secure pages is working fine.

**My GOAL**: I want the load balancer to handle all the SSL stuff, so that i wont have to configure SSL on individual tomcat servers.

**WHAT I DID**: I purchased an SSL certificate, and configured the certificate on a AWS Elastic Load Balancer, and added my tomcat instance.
*My Listeners are configured this way:-*
1. HTTP 80 -> HTTP 8080
2. HTTPS 443 -> HTTP 8443 [added SSL certificate to load-balancer here]

*TOMCAT 8080 port configuration*

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now, i am able to access my application by using load balancer.

**THE PROBLEM:** 
When i go to secure pages, the application is not functioning as expected. I have tried the below tomcat configuration, and i can access the secure pages, but the session is getting invalidated.
Any pointers on what i am missing here?

```
<Connector
port="8443"
sslProtocol="HTTP/1.1"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
proxyPort="443"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Added the following in my server.xml

NON-SSL port

```
<Connector 
port="8080"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="443" 
proxyPort="80"
proxyName="<my-website-url>" />
```

SSL port

```
<Connector
port="8443"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="false"
sslProtocol="TLS"
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
proxyName="<my-website-name>
proxyPort="443"
 />
```